# Python Image Processing: Measuring Layer Widths from Electron Micrograph

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scipy, python-imaging-library

I have an image from an electron micrograph depicting dense and rare layers in a biological system, as shown below.

[image: VDTap.png]

The layers in question are in the middle of the image, starting just to near the label "re" and tapering up to the left. I would like to:

1) count the total number of dark/dense and light/rare layers

2) measure the width of each layer, given that the black scale bar in the bottom right is 1 micron long

I've been trying to do this in Python. If I crop the image beforehand so as to only contain parts of a few layers, such the 3 dark and 3 light layers shown here:

[image: test.png]

I am able to count the number of layers using the code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image

tap = Image.open("VDtap.png").convert('L')
tap_a = np.array(tap)

tap_g = ndimage.gaussian_filter(tap_a, 1)
tap_norm = (tap_g - tap_g.min())/(float(tap_g.max()) - tap_g.min())
tap_norm[tap_norm < 0.5] = 0
tap_norm[tap_norm >= 0.5] = 1

result = 255 - (tap_norm * 255).astype(np.uint8)

tap_labeled, count = ndimage.label(result)

plt.imshow(tap_labeled)
plt.show()
```

However, I'm not sure how to incorporate the scale bar and measure the widths of these layers that I have counted. Even worse, when analyzing the entire image so as to include the scale bar I am having trouble even distinguishing the layers from everything else that is going on in the image.

I would really appreciate any insight in tackling this problem. Thanks in advance.

EDIT 1:

I've made a bit of progress on this problem so far. If I crop the image beforehand so as to contain just a bit of the layers, I've been able to use the following code to get at the thicknesses of each layer.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import ndimage
from PIL import Image
from skimage.measure import regionprops

tap = Image.open("VDtap.png").convert('L')
tap_a = np.array(tap)

tap_g = ndimage.gaussian_filter(tap_a, 1)
tap_norm = (tap_g - tap_g.min())/(float(tap_g.max()) - tap_g.min())
tap_norm[tap_norm < 0.5] = 0
tap_norm[tap_norm >= 0.5] = 1

result = 255 - (tap_norm * 255).astype(np.uint8)

tap_labeled, count = ndimage.label(result)

props = regionprops(tap_labeled)
ds = np.array([])

for i in xrange(len(props)):
    if i==0:
        ds = np.append(ds, props[i].bbox[1] - 0)
    else:
        ds = np.append(ds, props[i].bbox[1] - props[i-1].bbox[3])

    ds = np.append(ds, props[i].bbox[3] - props[i].bbox[1])
```

Essentially, I discovered the Python module skimage, which can take a labeled image array and return the four coordinates of a boundary box for each labeled object; the [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmYFK.png) and [3] positions give the x coordinates of the boundary box, so their difference yields the extent of each layer in the x-dimension. Also, the first part of the for loop (the if-else condition) is used to get the light/rare layers that precede each dark/dense layer, since only the dark layers get labeled by ndimage.label.

Unfortunately this is still not ideal. Firstly, I would like to not have to crop the image beforehand, as I intend to repeat this procedure for many such images. I've considered that perhaps the (rough) periodicity of the layers could be highlighted using some sort of filter, but I'm not sure if such a filter exists? Secondly, the code above really only gives me the *relative* width of each layer - I still haven't figured out a way to incorporate the scale bar so as to get the actual widths.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to be a party-pooper, but I think your problem is harder than you first thought.  I can't post a working code snippet because there are so many parts of your post that require in depth attention. I have worked in several bio/med labs and this work is usual done with a human to tag specific image points and a computer to calculate distances.  That being said, one should probably try to automate =D.

To you, the problem is a simple, yet tedious job, of getting out a ruler and making a few hundred measurements.  Perfect for a computer right?  Well yes and no.  The computer has no idea how to identify any of the bands in the picture and has to be told *exactly* what its looking for, and that will be tricky.

### Identifying the scale bar

What do you know about the scale bars in all your images.  Are they always the same number of vertical and horizontal pictures, are they always solid black?  Are there always just one bar (what about the solid line for the letter r)?  My suggestion is to try a [wavelet transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavelet_transform).  Imagine the 2d analog to the function

(probably helps to draw this function)
    f(x) = 
    0 if |x| > 1, 
    1 if |x| <1 && |x| > 0.5 
    -1 if |x| < 0.5

Then when our wavelet f(x, y) is convolved over the image, the output image will have high values only when it finds the black scale bar.  Also the length that I set to 1 can also be tuned for wavelets and that will help you find the scale bar too.

### Finding the ridges

I'd solve the above problem first because it seems easier and sets you up for this one.  I'd construct another wavelet for this one but just as a preprocessing step.  For this wavelet I'd try a 2d 0-sum box function again, but this try to match three (or more) boxes next to each other.  Also in addition to the height and width parameters for the box, we need a spacing and tilt angle parameter.  You probably don't have to get very close to the actual value, just close enough that the rest of the image blackens out.

### Measuring the ridges

There are lots and lots of ways to do this, but let's use our previous step for simplicity. Take your 3 box wavelet answer and it should be centered at the middle ridge and report a box "width" that is the average width of those three ridges it has captured.  Probably close enough considering how slowly the widths are changing!

Good hunting!